# Android SDK requires android developer toolkit version 17.0.0 or above

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am having this weird issue when I was trying to merge my projects from eclipse to netbeans. Now when trying to rerun eclipse I get this error

> "Android SDK requires android developer toolkit version 17.0.0 or
>   above"

What I have tried to do to resolve the issue was try and update the SDK and toolkit inside of it.

So far everything is updated and now I am clueless.

[image: Error message when starting up eclipse]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run software updates in Eclipse (Help > Check for Updates) and update the ADT.

Answer (score 22):

Go to your eclipse, click on Help -> install new software -> Add... -> type in 'ADT plugin' for name, type in 'https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/' for URL, then a couple selections including ADT will show up in the window, click on the things you want to update then click okay, and you will be able to update your ADT.

Answer (score 13):

1. In Eclipse go to Help.
2. Install New Software ---> Add inside Add Repository write the Name:
   ADT and Location:  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. after loading you will get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
4. check both if you want or check Developer Tools.
5. click Next
6. finish

Comment: When Help > Check for Updates didn't find any update this solution worked for me

Comment: That helped. I didnt know I have to check Developer tools. thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem. Tried to update through Help > Check for Updates, but was getting an alert message like this:

> Contacting software sites has encountered a problem

And after that the update process failed. Googled and found the solution.

You just need to add one line in eclipse.ini, which is located in Eclipse folder.
Add this line to the end of the file:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

And after that the update process went normally.

The problem lies in the fact that the upload process goes through IPv6, but the internet service provider supports IPv4.

[Source (russian)](http://drfits.com/2011/11/13/eclipse-contacting-software-sites-has-encountered-a-problem/)

Answer (score 1):

Just update your Android Developer Toolkit. It's automatically done through the included GUI updater/manager.

Comment: Like I said on my question, everything is updated to the max. Pretty much the android developer toolkit doesn't have any more updates than the 15. I couldn't run android sdk on eclipse since it is locked and can't be found so I had to update in on the folder location which everything is updated.

Comment: You're wrong. [Latest is 17](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), [also here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html)

Answer (score 0):

First update your Android SDK (it looks like you already did this)
Then perform update Eclipse

After the Eclipse is updated, make sure you have the latest Android plugins for Eclipse installed.

Last, in the Android SDK Manager plugin make sure your path to the updated Android SDK is correct.

Answer (score -1):

After I add the repository I see this message:
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target