# Android ADT version update throws error status

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am writing this after struggling a lot with updating my ADT. I have tried using different eclipse, android sdk everything, but still it says me that Android SDK requires android developer toolkit version 17.0.0 or above, current version is 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486.

I referred question mentioned here [Android SDK requires android developer toolkit version 17.0.0 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074532/android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-17-0-0-or-above)

But when I checked for updates again it displays a warning message stating that

**Warning: You are installing software that contains unsigned content. The authenticity or validity of this software cannot be established. Do you want to continue with the installation?**

along with the OK and Cancel buttons.

I got fed up of this, can any one tell me how to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: I tried that but still no use, it throws me error saying "An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling". "

Comment: Open ADT 17.zip-> plugins folder copy all JAR files.... then paste in your eclipse -> plugins folder. restart eclipse...

Comment: Where will I get ADT 17? I just downloaded ADT 18 from the developer site

Comment: okey then Copy jar files from ADT 18.zip and paste in eclipse->plugins folder

Comment: I did, but got the error while saving the workbench and getting same error when I restarted the eclipse. "An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
java.lang.NullPointerException

"

Comment: that also I tried hours back, I mean before replacing this ADT

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Also am not able to open my sdk manager. It says location has not been set in the preferences. But I have given the correct path and it was working for me before perfectly.

Comment: Oops, no result again :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is happening wrong with the eclipse or android sdk. I deleted literally everything except my workspace. Then installed again and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open the SDK manager(in Windows right click and run as administrator), and then update your Tools to the latest version. Install all the latest versions. That should solve your problem. Remember to open the SDK manager with administrator privileges.

Comment: Let me try this, but am using Ubuntu

Comment: In ubuntu use the `sudo` keyword for administrator privileges.

Comment: It would be better if you can tell more. And I installed new eclipse now and tried to install new ADT, but even then when I tried to set the SDK in the preferences, it is saying that parse SDK error and platform-tools is missing. Yes, it is missing! but can you can you tell me how to add that?

Comment: I am able to see this in my console, "DDMS files not found: /home/thejaswi/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb"

Comment: As far as I understand, there is no problem with the eclipse or ADT plugin. But the problem is with the android SDK. Update your android SDK to the latest version possible using the SDK manager. Your android SDK is the culprit here. Reinstall it and update it to the latest.

Comment: I would recommend reinstalling your android sdk from the scratch because that is creating the problem.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the new SDK from this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html for ubuntu. And sad factor is that I am not able to open literally anything including the SDK manager. When I click for SDK manager, it says location of sdk has not been set in the preferences

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10880/discussion-between-antrromet-and-tejas)